# Modeling with periodic functions

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

In the month of March, the temperature at the South Pole varies over the day in a periodic way that can be modeled approximately by a trigonometric function.
**The highest temperature is about $−50​$℃, and it is reached around $2$ p.m. The lowest temperature is about $−54​$℃ and it is reached half a day apart from the highest temperature at $2$ a.m.**
Find the formula of the trigonometric function that models the temperature $T$ at the South Pole in March $t$ hours since $2$ p.m. Define the function using radians.
The trig function for $T$=$2\cos(\frac{πt}{12})-52$
so my Question is at $2$ pm and at $2$ am temperature is high $−50​$℃ as given in question but when i plot the graph for the function T=$2\cos(\frac{πt}{12})-52$
 i get temperature at $2$ am the lowest i.e  $−54​$℃ why is it so?
[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are measuring time in hours from 2pm. So 2am corresponds to $t=12$, and so your temperature is:
$$
T=2\cos(\pi)-52=-54
$$
Which is correct. The temperature is at a maximum of $-50$ at 2pm and a minimum of $-54$ at 2am. Which is what the question is trying to say. The wording though is slightly confusing and you might be reading it as saying that it is a maximum at 2am?

Comment: "....you might be reading it as saying that it is a maximum at 2am?" Yeah so is these typo in question?

Comment: It is not a typo, it is slightly ambiguous wording:"The lowest temperature is about −54​℃ and it is reached half a day apart from the highest temperature at 2 a.m." means: "The lowest temperature is about −54​℃ and it is reached at 2 a.m. half a day apart from the highest temperature"